Send an email via SQL Server
I have tried to send emails from SQL Server via sp_send_dbmail. I have setup the Database Mail with the details for Hotmail (I also tried Google). It doesn't send and the queue is up to 1070.
The queue State is RECEIVES_OCCURING.
I have just had this event:

The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 15 (2024-11-20T09:25:29).


Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 204.79.197.212 (204.79.197.212:587), connect error 10060).

I have a profile called "SQL Admin":

Server Name: smtp.live.com
Port : 587
This server requires a secure connection - Basic Authentication

I'm baffled, looking in sysmail.sentitems and its empty. please let me know what further information you need to help me

I think it should be smtp-mail.outlook.com nowadays, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040 . Also, not sure database mail supports the new oath stuff, but you can try. In general, you should try to use another way of sending emails, since db mail doesn't support newer stuff

Database mail does not support the new oauth stuff, @siggemannen . It's going to be a real pain for a lot of us when basic auth gets turned off in the nearish future.

Yeah, we moved the emailing out of database long time ago and never looked back. Another alternative is not to use toy providers like microsoft, although, that might not be an option for everyone

Interesting, that document, @siggemannen , does suggest smtp-mail.outlook.com, however, we still use smtp.office365.com at the office. Another document also suggests the latter.

What did you provide for @enable_ssl parameter on the sysmail_add_account_sp call?

@ThomA Isn't that for professional 365 usage? I'm guessing OP wants to setup a hotmail forwarder address. I'm no expert though

I assumed office365, as I'm pretty sure hotmail/live accounts can't have basic SMTP auth enabled, @siggemannen ; I'm pretty sure that they require oauth. I could be completely misremembering though.

The DatabaseMail.exe process behind sp_send_dbmail that actually sends the mail messages uses the .NET class, System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, so only supports SMTP Basic authentication. i.e.: you won't be able to send through any mail server that requires OAuth or any other modern authentication method.

Looks like "Direct Send" is a possible solution.
